# Working with RadioButtonList in UserControl in jQuery

Tags: jquery

The below is the code in jQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("[id^='rdlAvailability_'][type='radio']").each(function () {
    $(this).change(function(){
        var radioBtnId = this.id;
        var $this = $(this);
        radconfirm('Are you sure you want to select this slot?', function(arg){
            if (arg == true) {
                $find('<%= FindControl("txtAvailability").ClientID %>').set_value("");
            }    
            else {
                $this.siblings('input').prop('checked',true);
                var rdlAvailability = document.getElementById(radioBtnId);
                rdlAvailability.checked = false;
                $this.prop('checked', false);
            }
        }, 300, 100,"");
    })
});
```

});

This is the markup for rdlAvailability for Monday

```
<table id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_MyAvailability_MyAvailabilityMonday_rdlAvailability" class="radio1" border="0" style="color: #004B59; font-size: 11px; font-family: Arial, Sans-serif; text-align: justify">
                        <tr>
                            <td><span disabled="disabled"><input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_MyAvailability_MyAvailabilityMonday_rdlAvailability_0" type="radio" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$MyAvailability$MyAvailabilityMonday$rdlAvailability" value="AVL01" disabled="disabled" /><label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_MyAvailability_MyAvailabilityMonday_rdlAvailability_0">Slot 0</label></span></td>
                        </tr><tr>
                            <td><input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_MyAvailability_MyAvailabilityMonday_rdlAvailability_1" type="radio" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$MyAvailability$MyAvailabilityMonday$rdlAvailability" value="AVL02" /><label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_MyAvailability_MyAvailabilityMonday_rdlAvailability_1">Slot 1</label></td>
                        </tr><tr>
                            <td><input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_MyAvailability_MyAvailabilityMonday_rdlAvailability_2" type="radio" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$MyAvailability$MyAvailabilityMonday$rdlAvailability" value="AVL03" /><label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_MyAvailability_MyAvailabilityMonday_rdlAvailability_2">Slot 2</label></td>
                        </tr><tr>
                            <td><input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_MyAvailability_MyAvailabilityMonday_rdlAvailability_3" type="radio" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$MyAvailability$MyAvailabilityMonday$rdlAvailability" value="AVL04" checked="checked" /><label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_MyAvailability_MyAvailabilityMonday_rdlAvailability_3">Slot 3</label></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
```

How can I make the jQuery code to work only for single time when click on Monday or any day. I have given the markup for Monday. Now I am getting 4 confirmation message boxes with this. It is not catching the right Availability Id of `rdlAvailability`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try binding the click directly and not in each function

```
$("[id^='rdlAvailability_'][type='radio']").on("change", function()
{
  // your code here
});
```